Criterion for a divisor to be the exceptional divisor of a blow up
Let $E$ be a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle over $\mathbb{P}^2$ in a smooth fourfold $X$. What is a sufficient condition to conclude that $X$ is the blow up of a smooth $X_0$ at a plane so that $E$ is the exceptional divisor? Is the normal bundle of $E$ in $X$ being $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ on the fiber sufficient?
Thanks in advance!

Yes, this is sufficient, see [Moĭšezon, B. G. The Castelnuovo-Enriques contraction theorem for arbitrary dimension. (Russian) Izv. Akad. Nauk SSSR Ser. Mat. 33 (1969), 974--1025.]
